# Python thread restart

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, reset

I have a thread when it is run it has an infinite loop.
When another thread is stopped, I wish to reset all the threads again,
There threads have sockets that transfer data between each other.
I am using

```
node1._Thread__stop()
```

function to stop the thread runing, but when I try to create a new thread with the same name:

```
node1 = node.node(8081,8082,token,1,"Node A",0)
node1.start()
```

It gives out an error

```
[Errno 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

I am not sure if the stop function worked on the threads, because I have a timeout clause for a socket that if it doesn't receive anything to print timeout. This prints after the error occured.

What would be a better reset of a thread/socket

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what are you looking for. However, I recommend you to have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/325528/183066) to a related question.

The important point is that isn't a good idea to terminate a thread when it's holding a resource such as a socket as in your case. The right way to do it would be to use any of the synchronization mechanisms (the answer referenced above uses an example with `threading.Event`, but it could be, for example, a `threading.Condition` if it suits your needs better) available to release the resource or, as it seems you need, reset some internal data to start from scratch.

I hope this helps.

Comment: that is the first thing I looked at actually before writing this question, I thought that his answer was too complicated for what I wish to have. I just simply wish to completely terminate or delete thread and socket. I do not need to save anything.

Comment: @user1009731 If you don't explicitly close a socket, it will remain upon until a timer at operating system level expires. Hence, you won't be able to re-open the socket for a while. I'm afraid you'll need to implement some thread synchronization to close that socket even if you don't need to keep any state.